# create a thread into setOnClickListener

Tags: android, multithreading, pthreads

I have an Intent into `setOnClickListener` that it open a list of contacts into a new activity,now,
when I test this example at AVD it is ok, but when I test
on a mobile phone as soon as I touch button I get closing message.

why ?!

Is need a Thread ?

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,Uri.parse("content://contacts/"));
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

    }});
```

My Manifest.xml

```
    <activity 
        android:name="com.example.ex21.ShoMyList"
        android:label="Picker">
        <intent-filter>

          <action android:name="Piker"></action>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
          <data android:path="contacts" android:scheme="content"></data>   

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ex21.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: is ShoMyList or ShowMyList?

Comment: ex21(my name program)closed...

Comment: ShoMyList, this is an simple example.

Comment: did you test my solution? post your `logcat`

Comment: I write this example from [Reto_Meier]Professional_Android_4_Application book, you can download this example from : www.uplooder.net/cgi-bin/dl.cgi?key=092c112903fd73bdbedbea26ffa5d25e

Comment: Shayan pourvatan : http://barnamenevis.org/showthread.php?431957-%D8%A7%D8%AC%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C-%DB%8C%DA%A9-%D8%AA%D8%B1%D8%AF-%D8%A8%D8%A7-%DA%A9%D9%84%DB%8C%DA%A9-%D8%B1%D9%88%DB%8C-%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%AA%D9%86

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://picker/contacts/"));
```

or

```
   Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
```

I think your uri is incorrect.

Comment: if this worked for you marked as answer that other people can use this

Comment: Ok,how I can do ? :-?